# Ruby date conversion

Tags: ruby, date, time

I have `Fri Jun 26 23:05:00 -0400 2009`
Which I'd like to convert into Eastern (US) time.
How can this be done with Ruby?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'tzinfo'

input_time = Time.parse('Fri Jun 26 23:05:00 -0400 2009')
input_time.utc
puts "input_time = #{input_time}"

est_tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('EST')

time_in_est = est_tz.utc_to_local(input_time)

puts "time_in_est = #{time_in_est}"
```

What we're doing here is:

- parse the given date string
- convert it to UTC
- use the tzinfo gem to lookup timezone info for 'EST' (which I'm assuming is what you meant by 'Eastern (US) time')
- convert the utc input time into a local time for the EST timezone

Answer (score 0):

http://tzinfo.rubyforge.org/doc/files/README.html

Part of activesupport